# how to submit form with fetched data from other component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

There are two components book and author

book form creates and post data

book.component.html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="bookForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4">Book Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" #name/>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4">Authors</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="author" [(ngModel)]="selectedAuthor" #author [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
         <option *ngFor="let author of authors" [value]="author._id" >{{author.name}}</option>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
          <button (click)="addBooks(name.value,author.value)"  class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

book.component.ts

```
export class BookcreateComponent implements OnInit {
  bookForm: FormGroup;
  authors:any;
  genres:any;
  public selectedAuthor:string;
  public selectedGenre:string;
  constructor(private dataService: DataStorageService, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.bookForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      language: ['', Validators.required],
      published: ['', Validators.required],
      pages: ['', Validators.required],
      author:[''],
      genre:[''],

    });
  }
  addBooks(name, author){
    this.dataService.addBooks(name, language, published, pages, author, genre);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
  getAuthors() {
    this.dataService.getAuthors().subscribe(
      data => { this.authors = data},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('author loaded')
    );
  }
```

json:

```
{
name:raj,
_id:3e32233edd222221
}
```

datastorgeservice.ts

```
addBooks(name,language,published,pages,author){
   const obj ={
     name:name,
     language:language,
     published:published,
     pages:pages,
     author:author,


   };
   this.http.post('http://testurl:3000/books',obj).subscribe(res=>console.log('done'));
  }
```

Here select box able to fetch data but while posting only name is getting posted successfully but author from author component fetched in select box is not submitted along with name.

Comment: You mean you can retrieve data and load it to the select box but while submitting the form only the name is getting posted Is that so?

Comment: yes exactly.I was able to retrieve data and load it but while posting only issue is there @SuvethanNantha

Comment: Do you want the whole author object to be passed? Can you attach the sample JSON that you retrieve? It will be easy for me construct the answer for you.

Comment: I want only the id of author to be posted but while displaying in select box it is displayed as name(this is done).I was able to fetch id also.Just need to post author id along with book name.check json format i have edited the question.

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement. You said you can get the id as well to addBooks function as well. Then you can directly pass it to addBooks service and get it done right? what's the issue in there? I think maybe issue is with your addBooks service function. If you can attach that as well to the question

Comment: There are two components books and authors.create book form has name and author name select.author name is retrived to book form in select option.while posting the form only name of book is getting posted to server and author name which is selected is not getting posted.sorry for my english.

Comment: If you don't mind can you attach the datastorageservice addBooks code as well? I will give you a solution for the problem.

Comment: Yes i have edited and added to this question.Please check it.Thanks in advance @SuvethanNantha

Comment: @SuvethanNantha did you find it?

Comment: check the answer and see whether you can achieve something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="bookForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4">Book Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" #name/>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4">Authors</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="author" [(ngModel)]="selectedAuthor" #author [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
         <option *ngFor="let author of authors" [value]="author._id" >{{author.name}}</option>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
          <button (click)="addBooks(name.value,author.value)"  class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
bookForm: FormGroup;
  authors:any;
  genres:any;
  public selectedAuthor:string;
  public selectedGenre:string;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router,private dataservice:DataStorageService) {
    this.createForm();
    this.getAuthors();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.bookForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      language: ['', Validators.required],
      published: ['', Validators.required],
      pages: ['', Validators.required],
      author:[''],
      genre:[''],

    });
  }
  addBooks(name, author){
    this.dataservice.addBooks(name,author).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('done');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }); 
  }
  getAuthors() {
    this.authors=[{
      name:'raj',
      _id:'3e32233edd222221'
      },{
      name:"roje",
      _id:"3e3223"
      }];
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
```

then import the **HttpModule** into NgModule.

**datastorageservice.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http,Request,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class DataStorageService {
    http:Http;


    constructor(http:Http){
        this.http=http;
    }


    addBooks (name,author) :Observable<Response>{
        const obj ={
          name:name,
          author:author  // author is equal to author id
        };
        console.log(obj); //{name: "book1", author: "3e32233edd222221"}
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post('http://testurl:3000/books', JSON.stringify(obj),options);
    }

}
```

If you want to go with HttpClient then check the demo linked below.

[Demo with Http and HttpClient](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbctkb)

Since you want to pass both book name and author id to the server side,you can follow the above code. I have tested this code with dummy values for the author select. I have retrieved both book name and author id up to http post. If it's still not going to server side then there should be some problems in server side. Please check.

I hope this will help you. If you have any issues or suggestion let me know.

Comment: Hi sorry bro.I am using httpclient angular 5.Request option are deprecated

Comment: New version of httpclient module doesn't support headers.It shows some version incompatible error.

Comment: you don't need httpclient use below one

import {Http,Request,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

for more details check the working demo

Comment: @Raj check the edited answer you don't need to use httpClient use http instead

Comment: Great Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168329/discussion-between-raj-and-suvethan-nantha).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the `[(ngModel)]="selectedAuthor"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedAuthor._id"` if you only want to send the id attribute in the post-request, otherwise you send the whole author-object, instead of just the one property you want to send.